# Freeing the heap on destructor

Tags: c++, winapi, memory, heap-memory

I have a class called 'Byte' that makes me allocate/deallocate dynamic memory.but i am having problem,i don't know where to free it on destructor ? or code new functions like free()

let me explain.

```
Byte string; // Default constructor created a heap saved in a private variable in class.

void assignsomething()
{
string += "Blabla"; // Created a block of memory
string += " Blabla2"; // Added data again.

} // if I write a destructor that free heap with HeapDestroy() i can't use data in main()

int main()
{
  assignsomething();
  MessageBoxA(0,string,0,0);
  // Byte.HeapFree(); 
}
```

Now... is it possible to set where destructor will be calling ? 
or i should call free when i'm done with class ?
Thanks in advance.
Happy coding.

Comment: please could post Byte code?

Comment: Why can't you use it in main if its destructor frees memory? Its destructor is called after main.

Comment: Are you saying that the Byte class itself frees the contained memory in its dtor, or that you need to call some method on it to free this memory?

Comment: I can but coded in my mother language and codes lines are > 200.
I'm doing something like this but it call destructor on assignsomething() function ?

Comment: Byte class creates a Heap and makes processes over it.like allocation deallocation but the problem is Byte class destructor calling on end of assignsomething()

Comment: I can thing of a virutally *endless* list of better names for that variable than "string" in a C++ program.

Comment: We need to see the code for Byte, otherwise we can't know what constructors and operators are defined for it, which can change the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create it on the stack (you don't create it via new) then the destructor will be called automatically when it goes out of scope.  If you create it via new, you need to free it yourself by using operator delete when you're done with it.  Do NOT call free() on it, use the new and delete operators.  Do not try to call the destructor by hand, just use delete

And yes, the destructor should release all dynamically allocated memory left in the class, unless you have a pointer to it outside the class.  Try not to do that, it makes memory management hard and is generally considered bad design.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, you take memory, and in the destructor you free it.
It's automatique with local or static varaibles, but when you have a "new", you must use a "free" or "delete" or something else to tell the operating system that this part of memory is useless now for you, and the OS can take it back